# Understanding an equation used in the Xavier initialization for deep neural networks paper

Tags: variance, neural-networks

I'm trying to understand an equation from the paper "Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks", available [here](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf). The equation in question is on the bottom left of page 5.

The authors write, assuming $f$ is linear.

> For a dense artificial neural network using symmetric activation
> function $f$ with unit derivative at $0$ , if we write $z^i$ for the
> activation vector of layer $s$ and $s^i$ the argument vector of the
> activation function at layer $i$, we have $s^i = z^i W^i + b^i$ and
> $z^{i+1} = f(s^i)$. From these definitions we obtain the following:
>
> $ \frac{\partial Cost} {\partial w^{i}_{l,k}} = z^{i}_{l}
>   \frac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^{i}_{k}}$ , and $\frac{\partial
>   Cost}{\partial s^{i}_{k}} = f'(s^{i}_{k}) W^{i+1}_{k, :}\frac{\partial
>   Cost}{\partial s^{i}_k}$.
>
> The variances will be expressed with respect to the input, output and
> weight initialization randomness. Consider the hypothesis that we are
> in a linear regime at the initialization, that the weights are
> initialized independently and that the input features variances are
> the same $( = Var[x])$. Then we can say that, with $n_i$ the size of
> layer $i$ and $x$ the network input,
>
> $f'(s^{i}_{k})  \approx 1$ and $Var[z^i] = Var[x]
> \Pi_{i'=0}^{i-1}n_i'Var[W^i]$.

From what I understand this last statement follows from the assumption that $E[x] = E[W^i] = 0$, and hence follows from the formula that for two independent random variables $X,Y$, that $Var(XY) = Var(X)Var(Y) + E(X)^2Var(Y) + E(Y)^2Var(X)$.

Next the authors write:

> We write $Var[W^i]$ for the shared scalar variance of all weights at
> layer $i'$. Then for a network with $d$ layers,
>
> \begin{equation} Var[ \frac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^i}] =
>  Var[\frac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^d}] \Pi_{i'=i}^{d} n_{i'+1} Var
>  [W^i]  \tag{1}\end{equation}
>
> \begin{equation} Var[\frac{\partial Cost}{\partial w^i}] =
>   \Pi_{i'=0}^{i-1} n_{i'} Var [W^{i'}] \Pi_{i'=i}^{d-1} n_{i'+1} Var
>   [W^{i'}] Var[x] Var [\frac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^d}] \tag{2}
>   \end{equation}

I'm trying to understand equation $1)$ and $2)$ tagged above. For equation $1)$ since $\frac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^i} = \frac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^{i+1}} \frac{\partial s^{i+1} }{\partial s_i}$, where $s_1 = W^{1} x + b^{i}$, and the fact that $Var[W^i x] = Var[W^i]Var[x]$, and $\frac{\partial s^{i+1} }{\partial s_i} = W^{i}$, I think the result follows.

I'm not sure how to derive equation $2)$, any insights appreciated.

Comment: It looks like they split:
$$\begin{array}{r c l}  Var[\frac{\partial Cost}{\partial w^i}] & = &  Var[\frac{\partial Cost}{\partial s^i}\frac{\partial s^i}{\partial w^i}]\\  \end{array}$$